# Purposeful MYSQL duplicate entries in association table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using Python and SQLAlchemy to connect to a MYSQL database.

What I have is a type Membership, a type MembershipType and a relationship. Membership has a list of MembershipType called 'listMembershipTypeObjects'. They are both connected to the MYSQL database via an association table called 'AssociationTable_Membership_MembershipTypes'. That looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `associationtable_membership_membershiptypes` (
`ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`MembershipID` int DEFAULT NULL,
`MembershipTypeID` int DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
KEY `MembershipID` (`MembershipID`),
KEY `MembershipTypeID` (`MembershipTypeID`),
CONSTRAINT `associationtable_membership_membershiptypes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MembershipID`)   REFERENCES `memberships` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `associationtable_membership_membershiptypes_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`MembershipTypeID`)   REFERENCES `membershiptypes` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

There are a few membership types like 'Bronze' and 'Silver'.

Here's the key part: some memberships can contain more than one of the same type of MembershipType. So, for example, a Membership's listMembershipTypeObjects could contain 'Silver', 'Silver'. I can add that MembershipType twice in my Python program, but when I commit, it only adds one entry to the association table. I had hoped this would work since I have not made the membershipID or the membershipTypeID unique (and they are not unique as a combination).

I've checked the list on the line before the commit statement and it tells me I have two items in the list, (both 'Silver' in this case), but then when I check the DB it shows only one item in the association table. It's the right one, but there's only one where I would like there be two.

Is this just a case of me making a mistake somewhere, or do I need to change something in order to make this the behaviour?

There also seems to be a problem on getting the data. I have tried adding that duplicate entry myself (I should say that there was no error on this manual adding):

```
ID: 1 MembershipID: 7 MembershipTypeID: 2
ID: 2 MembershipID: 7 MembershipTypeID: 2
```

That's all the association table contains, just to be sure. When I get all the Membership records, I can inspect record 7 and see its list. One item. Oh my god why.

Comment: "I can add that MembershipType twice in my Python program" - Are you creating a single MembershipType object and adding it twice, or are you creating two distinct MembershipType objects that both have the same descriptor ("Silver")? If you add the same object (e.g., `<__main__.MembershipType object at 0x000000409BE9B9D0>` twice then SQLAlchemy will probably recognize that they are *the same* object and de-dupe them.

Comment: Yes, same type added twice.

Comment: Well, I shall add another to clarify. Same object, same location in memory for the two MembershipTypes in the list.